# Is there a `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a` function type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

So `>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` and `>> :: m a -> m b -> m b`.

whereas `<* :: f a -> f b -> f a`.

But I want something that does `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a`, i.e. actually discards the computation result and keeps the original.  In my case, this computation result is just an IO operation that returns `()` so I just need to pass the original value along.

Is there such a function?  If not, how do I compose one?  Haven't managed to figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: `fconst f = join $ (.f).(<$)` - its type is `(a->f b)->a->f a`, which has the same meaning.

Comment: @SassaNF Not it hasn't. He asked for `f a -> (a -> f b) -> f a`

Comment: @Cubic :) but you get that with `mx >>= fconst f` - which actually brings me to the point why it is useful with the arguments this way around, and with `a` instead of `m a`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
discardResult mx mf = do x <- mx
                         mf x
                         return x
```

Though jozefg's solution is simpler.

Comment: There's a difference. In your answer `mx` action will be executed only once. In @jozefg's answer `m` action will be executed two times.

Comment: Thanks!  Inspired by this I made a lamdba i.e. `\x -> (mf x) >> return x`, which seems simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
discard :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m a
discard g f = g >>= ((>>) <$> f <*> return)
```

Uses the `Applicative` instance of `(->)` to make it a little shorter, but is otherwise equivalent to Alexey's answer. Of course this requires `Control.Applicative` but since you mentioned `<*` I figured you already had that one.

E.g: `discard getLine print` reads a line, prints it and then returns the string read.

Comment: `liftA2 (>>) f return` reads nicer than the operator soup you have, in my opinion.

Comment: @kqr I suppose it depends on what you're used to. I like the "operator soup" because it extends to functions of any arity.

Comment: Oh, for sure I like using the operators for most things. It's just in this particular case (or indeed any time the variables are shorter than the operators) I think it gets noisy.